# Symfony form type display ManyToOne entity information

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I'm creating a form type to update options for accounts the user have.

I have 3 entities `User`, `UserHasAccount` and `Account`.

Here are the relations between them:

`User` (OTM) <-> (MTO) `UserHasAccount` (MTO) <-> (OTM) `Account`

In `UserHasAccount` I have 2 options `options1` and `options2` (boolean)

An account can be link to multiple user. I have a page where I want to be able to change the options foreach `Users` linked to this `Account` (`/account/{id}/manage-user`)

Here is the first form type to map the fields from `User`

```
class AccounUserOptionFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AcmeUserBundle:User',
                'property' => 'fullname',
            ))
            ->add('option1', 'checkbox', array(
                'label' => 'account.form.option.one',
                'required' => false,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
            ))
            ->add('option2', 'checkbox', array(
                'label' => 'account.form.option.two',
                'required' => false,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserHasAccount',
            'translation_domain' => 'AcmeAccountBundle'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_update_account_option_type';
    }
}
```

And the AccountUserOption form type:

```
class AccountUserOptionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // Display the collection of users
            ->add('accountUser', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new AccountUserOptionFormType($options),
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\Account',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'validation_groups' => array('AcmeUpdateOption'),
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_account_user_option_type';
    }
}
```

The problem I have is with:

```
->add('user', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeUserBundle:User',
    'property' => 'fullname',
))
```

I just want to display (label or similar) the name of the user. Using entity is displaying a dropdown :/ Is there any core field type I could use or do I have to create a custom one? I would have think that this could be core.

Cheers, 
Maxime